# перемещение изображения при скролле вверх

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть данный код:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).width() > 1000) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 400) {
      $(".img").animate({
        "right": "+50px",
        "top": "+800px",
        "opacity": "0"
      }, 4000);
    }
  }
});
```

при скролле вниз перемещается и исчезает изображение корректно, подскажите как сделать возвращение элемента в его исходное положение при смене положения <400, заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var topOffset = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log(topOffset);
  if (topOffset >= 50) {
    $(".img").animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, 1000);
  } else if (topOffset < 50) {
    $(".img").animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="img">
```

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению при данном коде проблема осталась такая же, при скролле вниз изображение принимает opacity = 0, при прокрутке страницы вверх, остается нулевым, библиотека jqerry подключена 2.1.4, подключал так же 2.1.1